# How to derive Marginalization?

Tags: probability

How would you derive marginalization as it is given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution?

Thanks,

Comment: It is consensus that questions be self contained, so please write whatever it is that you're referencing in the page in your question's body. Thank you!

Comment: The Wikipedia article you refer to has a good deal of detail, with some worked examples. If you have a *concrete* problem you are having difficulty with, perhaps you could give it explicitly.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff The wikipedia page gives the PDF and says to marginalize you integrate. How would you derive marginalization starting from I assume Bayes Theorem?

Comment: A very good question. Perhaps you get better answers if you would state it as: "How to prove the Chapman–Kolmogorov equation?" (in its general form, not the variant limited to Markov chains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marginalizing amounts to integrating or summing out from joint distributions of several variables to the distribution of a smaller number of variables, usually to one variable.  So for example if X and Y have the joint desnsity f(x,y) to get the maginal density for X you compute g(x)=∫f(x,y)dy integrated over all possible values of y.  You do the analogous thing with sums for discrete variables.